# Adding Text To Function In Title Of Graph

Tags: excel

If I go to Select Data in Excel chart, and then to Edit one of the series, Excel does not resolve this formula as the name of the series:

`=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!$D$7, " accounts")`

... although it resolves it if I enter it in any cell in a sheet.

My question is - how can I add text (concatenate) to a function in a title of a chart.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Excel cannot have a function within a chart title. Only cell references.

[Here's a link](https://www.excelbanter.com/charts-charting-excel/172804-concatenate-chart-titles.html) that discusses it.